# How to add to cart drf

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have already asked this question but I got no response can you please elaborate how should I proceed. I am trying to create the order but i stuck at logic.

models.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      image_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      image_size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      file_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      price = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title


class Order(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
      start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
      ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.user)
```

serializers.py:

```
class AddtocartSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = OrderItem
            fields = ['image_number','title','image_size','file_type','price']



class CartSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
      class Meta:
           model = Order
           fields = ['item',
                     'start_date',
                     'ordered_date'
              ]
```

views.py:

```
class AddtocartView(generics.CreateAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      pagination_class = None
      queryset=OrderItem.objects.all()
      serializer_class = AddtocartSerializers


class CartView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      pagination_class = None
      queryset=Order.objects.all()
      serializer_class = CartSerializers

      def create(self, request):        
          return super(AddtocartView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```
path('addtocart/',views.AddtocartView.as_view(),name='addtocart'),
path('cart/',views.CartView.as_view(),name='cart'),
```

how can i create order after addtocart?

Answer (score 0):

First of my suggestion for you don't to use ModelViewSet, because all you need is create and update for you view, for create use CreateAPIView, for update RetrieveAPIView.
you code will be like below:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id', 'image_number', 'image_size', 'file_type', 'price']

class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    items = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=OrderItem.objects.all(), required=True), required=True)
    ordered_date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['user', 'items', 'ordered_date']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user 
        instance = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class CartView(CreateAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      queryset=Order.objects.all()
      serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer

      def create(self, request):
          return super(AddtocartView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

ModelViewSet include more code which you don't use in you case. And also you can get user from request, and you can just add

```
validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
```

Comment: why you are getting all the user ordercreateserializers? it should create or update order of current user

Comment: @afk I am getting all user, I am getting current user who making request to create order

Comment: but its not creating order after addtocart click

Comment: all you above views is get request, not post also addtocart get request @afk

Comment: as you can see the edits views are making post request but i still stuck at create or update order after addtocart

Comment: @afk problem on creating orderItem?

Comment: problems on creating cart after orderitem gets created cart not updating or creating

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a post request to addtocart endpoint. But there must be logic written in addtocart endpoint to create an order and add OrderItem to the order. Then the order number must be returned to browser so that user can resume shopping / checkout the order.

After receiving the order number you can do some javascript stuff to show user his order details.

Comment: should i create the logic in serializers or views

Comment: I would recommend views.